# Z-Index not working correctly on absolute objects

Tags: html, css

I am having some issues with absolute objects on a website. Z-index essentially won't work correctly. I may be being a little dumb?

Here is the website: http://www.mascots.ds-demo.co.uk/

The blue and yellow characters need to be behind the hero cta buttons 'learn more' and 'get a quote' however i cant get them to work with z-index.

CSS on characters:

```
.character-blue-float {
position: absolute;
float: right;
top: 7%;
left: -20%;
z-index: 1000;
-ms-transform: rotate(7deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
transform: rotate(7deg);
}

.character-blue-float img {
width: auto;
max-width: 800px;
height: auto;
}
```

CSS on Buttons:

```
.home-hero-cta {
margin-top: 30px;
z-index: 2000;
}

.btn-outer-lrg {
padding: 10px 20px;
color: #08788c;
border: 2px solid #08788c;
border-radius: 5px;
font-size: 22px;
background-color: transparent;
margin-right: 10px;
font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
}
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply below css to `hero-home` and check

```
.hero-home {
  z-index: 1001;
  position: relative;
}
```

it should work

[image]

Comment: A small typo.. it should be `z-index`, not `zindex`